# Can't access even logged in (MVC 3 Authentication)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I wrote this in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/en/Account/LogIn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

and this in an action in the controller:

```
[Authorize]
        public ActionResult AccountInfo()
        {
            return view()
        }
```

now, when I run the program - and try to get to the account-info view -it doesn't bring me there, what very fine. But when I logged in and try to get to this view - it also doesn't let me the view, what very bad...

I did the authentication thing just because I wanted to let only logged in users to have an access to my site, not to prevent them as well. 
How do I give them the access?

thank in advance.

---

**solved**

I needed to write the url in this place and like this:

```
<location path="~/en/Account/LogIn">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

instead of `<authentication> <form>` , write it in `<location>`

Comment: The solution above simply says allow everyone access to account/login. Generally in MVC thus approach is frowned upon and all security should be at the controller level. I don't see how thus has any bearing on your login URL unless you were protecting the login controller with an [authorize] attribute as well?

Comment: Of course I wasn't protecting the login controller so the not logged in users could log in. In Fact, and this is the only thing I know -once I did this movement - it has changed for the better.

Comment: this is odd, something else is going on as this is not required. hmm..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to write the url in this place and like this:

```
<location path="~/en/Account/LogIn">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

instead of `<authentication> <form>` , write it in `<location>`

Answer (score 0):

Was this site orionally webmatrix based? If the webmatrix library is in your reference and used it overrides the URL set in your web.config

Comment: My site is not orionally webmatrix based.

Comment: And if I just add /en before the /account/login - it's all right..           Whre can it be written else?

Comment: what do you mean if you add the /en before it.. do you mean without the ~?

Comment: no,I mean in the url path in the browser. I meant to say that where I defined the url in web.config - I wrote the en/ thing but in the browser when the program run - it is without this (/en). this is not the full path. I just wanted to add /en to where the browser take the partial url but I didn't understand where it can be either.